# What is the difference between "with" and "with recursive" in sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I found this SQL code to generate Fibonacci sequence here
https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/databases/SQLite/sql/with/recursive/fibonacci

If "with recursive" is replaced by "with", the code generate the same sequence. So I'm wondering what is the difference between "with" and "with recursive"?

Comment: Here's a good [writeup](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-common-table-expressions-cte/) about it. Have to say, it was about 3 on the search results list.

Answer (score 1):

> So I'm wondering what is the difference between "with" and "with recursive"?

Nothing functionality wise. The `RECURSIVE` token is optional (see screen shot) but serves to indicate that recursion takes place. Recursion itself is determined by the CTE's as per

> A SELECT statement is a recursive if its FROM clause contains exactly one reference to the the CTE table (the table named on the left-hand side of the AS clause).

[image]

Screen shot and quote from **[The With Clause](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html)**

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I searched railroad diagram and now I understand what it means. thanks